# NSD_CreateNumber error message language

Tags: nsis

For a text box dedicated for numbers (using NSD_CreateNumber), if the user happens to type non-numeric characters, an error message pops-up in the form.

The problem is that this error message is displayed with OS language and not with the language configured for the wizard.

Is there a way to customize this message or its idiom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message appears in standard edit boxes with the [ES_NUMBER style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775464(v=vs.85).aspx) on WinXP+ and NSIS does not really have anything to do with the popup.

The only way to display a different message would be to write your own NSIS plugin that subclasses the edit box and displays it's own popup...